# How to use Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I just recently discovered Boost.Python and I am trying to figure out how it works. I tried to go through [the tutorial on the official website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/hello.html). However, I got

```
link.jam: No such file or directory
```

when running bjam as in the example (which appears to be just a warning),
and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 7, in <module>
import hello_ext
ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when running python hello.py.

I also tried to compile a module as described in [another tutorial](http://www.shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/) with similar results. I am running Ubuntu14.04 with boost1.55 compiled myself.

---

I tried to compile the following:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

with the following command from command line:

```
g++ -o hello_ext.so hello.cpp -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -I /home/berardo/boost_1_55_0/ -L /usr/lib/python2.7/ -L /home/berardo/boost/lib/ -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -Wl, -fPIC -expose-dynamic
```

which still gives me a:

```
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare : File o directory non esistente
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Comment: Did you build your boost libraries with the Python library enabled? Do the appropriate boost python binaries exist and are they in library search path? Why not just use the boost packages that already exist for Ubuntu? Looking at the package database, it seems that boost 1.55 exists on Ubuntu 14.04 [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdevel/libboost1.55-all-dev).

Comment: @Dan I installed the boost libraries against python2.7, since I needed this version. However I was not able to figure out how to do this with the standard ubuntu package database. Just for completeness, I installed boost to use a software called hoomd but I had no problems building the last one with boost

Comment: Hmm, looking at the command you used in your attempt to build manually, I see `-Wl, -fPIC -expose-dynamic` at the end. That doesn't seem right. `-fPIC` is a compiler option. `-Wl,option` passes option to the linker. The linker should be passed an option `--export-dynamic`. There should not be a space between the comma and the option.

Comment: Did you try any more to get the module you compiled with bjam to work? That seems to have built properly, the system just can't find your custom .so which you probably didn't install into any standard location. Look at section 3.5 in [this HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) or for the start, just copy the boost dependencies your module into the same directory where it's located.

Comment: @Rebrado Please post the solution as an answer, not as an edit to your question. It's fine, and in fact encouraged, to answer your own question if you figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to make it work. First, I fixed the linker issues, as suggested by Dan. It finally compiled but I still got:

```
ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem was that the python module was not able to load correctly so I needed to add another linker option. Here, I report the final Makefile:

```
# location of the Python header file
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = ${HOME}/boost/include
BOOST_LIB = ${HOME}/boost/lib

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello_ext

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,-rpath,$(BOOST_LIB) -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).C
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).C
```

Notice the **-Wl,-rpath,** option, which apparently makes the new created shared library available to the python script.
@Dan: Thanks for the valuable hints.

Comment: You do not need `-Wl,--export-dynamic` for linking shared libraries. Only for linking executables.